# How to search any word in linux 'screen'

Tags: linux, search, terminal, gnu-screen

I am going screen logs of devstack with following command. 
`screen -x stack` 
I find searching in screens very difficult. Currently I start copy mode with 
`Ctrl` `A` `Esc` and read all the logs, sometimes it is very irritating to go through all logs while searching for a single word.

Is there a good way for searching a word in screens?

from `man screen` I found

```
    Searching:
     / Vi-like search forward.
     ? Vi-like search backward.
     C-a s Emacs style incremental search forward.
     C-r Emacs style reverse i-search.
```

but screens do not support vi-like forward search.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Once you are in scrollback mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, you should be able to search backwards through the buffer as described in the manual.

So to search for the word "string", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, enter `?string` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will take you backwards through the buffer to the word string. Pressing <kbd>N</kbd> will go to the next match (backwards) in the buffer.

To search forwards, the cursor should be anywhere but the end of the buffer, then use `/string` to search down.

Comment: This might be my most visited Q/As on SO.

Comment: Scrollback mode seems to work a lot like `less` - `/string` and `?string` search downwards and upwards.  `n`/`N` find the next/previous match.  `g`/`G` jump to the top/bottom of the output.

Comment: N aborts the copy mode for me. It does not reverse the search.

Comment: `N aborts the copy mode for me. It does not reverse the search.` Same here — any ideas how to reverse search?

Comment: @martin-klosi @ebarrere If  `N aborts the copy mode for me. It does not reverse the search.` then you can try using `Control + R` instead of `N`. That should do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, there is a search button in the menu bar. You can search backwards/forward or even search with regular expressions as well.

[image]

Comment: this does not work if you are in the screens for example byobu. Answer from @ian-petts works perfectly. Thanks :)